# How to replace some of the values in Helm template definition?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a value `someField` in my `values.yaml` file that looks like this:

```yaml
someField:
  field1: 1
  field2: someValue
  field3: someObject
  ...
```

I now want to add this to my template, but change some of the fields and add some other fields and maybe remove some of them too.

```yaml
someField:
  field1: 2
  field3: someObject
  ...
  field100: someNewValue
```

I can write to my template all the fields one by one and then do what I want, but there are multiple fields that are available and I would like to avoid listing them all.

I can use `toYaml`, but it would fully write the original value, and I do not know how to augment it "on the fly"

Extended example:

I have another helm chart installed that is called KEDA, and it defines a CRD:

```yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: {scaled-object-name}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion:    {api-version-of-target-resource}  # Optional. Default: apps/v1
    kind:          {kind-of-target-resource}         # Optional. Default: Deployment
    name:          {name-of-target-resource}         # Mandatory. Must be in the same namespace as the ScaledObject
    envSourceContainerName: {container-name}         # Optional. Default: .spec.template.spec.containers[0]
  pollingInterval:  30                               # Optional. Default: 30 seconds
  cooldownPeriod:   300                              # Optional. Default: 300 seconds
  idleReplicaCount: 0                                # Optional. Default: ignored, must be less than minReplicaCount 
  minReplicaCount:  1                                # Optional. Default: 0
  maxReplicaCount:  100                              # Optional. Default: 100
  fallback:                                          # Optional. Section to specify fallback options
    failureThreshold: 3                              # Mandatory if fallback section is included
    replicas: 6                                      # Mandatory if fallback section is included
  advanced:                                          # Optional. Section to specify advanced options
    restoreToOriginalReplicaCount: true/false        # Optional. Default: false
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:                   # Optional. Section to specify HPA related options
      name: {name-of-hpa-resource}                   # Optional. Default: keda-hpa-{scaled-object-name}
      behavior:                                      # Optional. Use to modify HPA's scaling behavior
        scaleDown:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
          - type: Percent
            value: 100
            periodSeconds: 15
  triggers:
  - type: service-bus
    authenticationRef: name-of-auth
```

I have my own HelmChart where I want to generate this CRD from a definition, but change some values.

So a user would provide spec, but I would augment it by e.g. adding 'authenticationRef' to every element of the triggers array.

Comment: Can you give some more details of how this value is used; what does the actual Helm template code look like?  If you're adding more values but don't necessarily want to use all of them, what would make a specific value like `field42` included or not?  Is the idea that the first block of values would be in the chart's `values.yaml` file, but the second a `helm install -f` per-installation settings file?

Comment: I have added more details on what I want to achieve, please check if that made the intent more clear.